# Using Navigation property inside navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have 3 domain models PdModel, PdTable, PdColumn. relationship between tables is quite simple - PdModel has many PdTables and PdTable has many PdColumns. What I need is to populate my IndexModel so I can fill my dropdown buttun using razor syntax - for example selecting dropdown for models, then at specific model next dropdown level for that models tables and again for that tables columns.

Here I found hint, but it doesn't work: [Populating navigation properties of navigation properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131306/populating-navigation-properties-of-navigation-properties)

according to this url my Index method looks like this:

```
PdFolderTree =  _context.pdFolderTree.Include(x => x.pdModels)
                                                  .Include(x => x.pdModels.Select(y => y.PdTables))
                                                  .ToList();
```

Error I get is:
InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'x => {from PdModel y in x.pdModels select [y].PdTables}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

I'm using .NET Core razor-pages/MVC.

Anyone dealt with something similar in the past?

Thanks

```
public class PdModel
{ 
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PdTable> PdTables { get; set; } 

}

public class PdTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModelId")]
    public virtual PdModel PdModels { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PdColumn> PdColumns { get; set; }

} 

public class PdColumn
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TableId")]
    public PdTable pdTable { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `.ThenInclude()`

The Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels) you link to gives this example:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
        .ToList();
}
```

So I think you would need to do:

```
PdFolderTree =  _context.pdFolderTree.Include(tree => tree.pdModels)
                              .ThenInclude(model => model.PdTables)
                              .ThenInclude(table => table.PdColumns)).ToList();
```

I haven't tested this, but it should give you a list of whatever `pdFolderTree` is and it should have all of the navigation properties populated.